# how to log Bad Request in Dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard

We are using Dropwizard 1.0.6 for our Java service. It seems that Dropwizard has eaten some (maybe all) Bad Request (400) error logs as we cannot see it from the service log.

What do we need to do to make sure we log ALL errors including errors reported by Dropwizard components?

Thanks.

Comment: you can tell DW to not register the default exception handlers and supply your own. 404's however are handled by the container (jetty) as they never even reach the resource classes.